# Why the value is undefined when creating edit function in Node Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

So the edit function supposed to edit the naskah title and naskah details with the selected id using modal window in HTML but it seems that can be read, the value of naskah title and details cannot, what is the solution to this?

Edit Button in Handlebars HTML :

```
    <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info edit" data-id="{{id}}" data-naskah_title=" 
      {{naskah_title}}" data-naskah_details="{{naskah_details}}">Edit</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" data-id="{{id}}">Delete</
    </td>
```

in Modal Window this is the form :

```
    <form action="naskah_form/update" method="post">
            <div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
              labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Naskah</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="naskah_title" class="form-control naskah_title" 
                            placeholder="Naskah Title" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="naskah_details" class="form-control details" 
                            placeholder="Naskah Details" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" class="naskah_id">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                        dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is the Jquery :

```
     <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mytable').on('click','.edit',function () {
                var naskah_id = $(this).data('id')
                var naskah_title = $(this).data('naskah_title')
                var naskah_details = $(this).data('naskah_details')
                $('#EditModal').modal('show');
                $('.naskah_title').val(naskah_title)
                $('.details').val(naskah_details)
                $('.naskah_id').val(naskah_id)
            })
        })
      </script>
```

This is the function for form POST in Node js Using Express Js :

```
    router.post('/update',(req,res)=>{
       console.log(req.body.title)
       console.log(req.body.details)
       console.log(req.body.id)
    })
```

The result is :

> undefined undefined 2 // 2 is the id and it seems only the id that can be read

*Note : I have install all jquery,body parser,etc in app.js which i use the express framework for node js and i already set and use app.use in app.js

Comment: Should be `req.body.naskah_title` and `req.body.naskah_details` in your route handler to correspond to the names of your form fields.

Comment: The name of your input is different than what is submitted `title` => `naskah_title`